# How to get subcategory with their category in django models and showing in templates

Tags: python-3.x, django, python-3.8

I want to present my skill category with their subcategories list.
I am facing issue while fetching the data from models to views.
my code is given below:

**model.py** Here I create 2 classes **SkillCategory** and **SkillSubCategory**

```
class SkillCategory(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category

class SkillSubCategory(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(SkillCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subcategory = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    icon_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.subcategory
```

**views.py** Here I define a function based view named as **skill** which return list of list

```
def skill(request):
    allsubcat = []
    skillcat = SkillSubCategory.objects.values()
    cat = {c['subcategory'] for c in skillcat}
    for c in cat:
        skill = SkillSubCategory.objects.filter(subcategory=c)
        allsubcat.append([skill])
    ctx = {'allsubcat':allsubcat}
    return render(request, "my_folio/skill.html", ctx)
```

**skill.html** This is the template which should present the Skill like:

- Skill Category 1

  - Skill SubCat 1
  - Skill SubCat 2
- Skill Category 2

  - Skill SubCat 1
  - Skill SubCat 2
  - Skill SubCat 3

Could anyone please help me for the given issue.
Thanks and cheers!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can add related name like this for reverse relationship

```
class SkillSubCategory(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(SkillCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="skill_subcategories")
    subcategory = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    icon_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.subcategory
```

in view context you can pass only skills

```
def skill(request):
    skills_categories = SkillCategory.objects.all()
    ctx = {'skill_categories': skills_categories}
    return render(request, "my_folio/skill.html", ctx)
```

In template you can iterate like this

```
<ul>
    {% for category in skill_categories %}
    <li>{{ category.category }}</li>
    <ul>
        {% for subcategory in category.skill_subcategories.all %}
            <li>{{ subcategory.category }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks Dude! But I have to add one more this in you code  <li>{{ subcategory.subcategory }}</li>. And it works fine for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Bro I have one more doubt if you can help then please ping me on any platform.
shubhamkgupta.in
Thanks, I am waiting for your reply...

Answer (score 0):

Pass only the `SkillCategory` queryset in the context:

```
def skill(request):
    skill_categories = SkillCategory.objects.all()
    ctx = {'skill_categories': skill_categories}
    return render(request, "my_folio/skill.html", ctx)
```

Now in the template you can loop like so:

```
<ul>
    {% for skill_category in  skill_categories %}
        <li>{{ skill_category.category }}
            <ul>
                {% for skill_subcategory in skill_category.skillsubcategory_set %}
                    <li>{{ skill_subcategory.subcategory }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Where `skillsubcategory_set` is just the related model name in lowercase with _set appended. Django adds this attribute to your model for each related field to the model (**Note:** _set will be appended only for Relations of the form One to Many and Many to Many, also you can specify the name using `related_name` attribute on any ForeignKey, OneToOneField, ManyToManyField, etc.).